# What does `Var2 DW Var1` mean in TurboShell/TurboAsm?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, data-segment

why does the following code compile perfectly?

```
Data Segment

Var1 Dw (any 4 digit hex value)
Var2 Dw Var1

Data Ends
```

what does the line "Var2 Dw Var1" even mean?
I thought that only an immediate value can go after the type defining .

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: TurboShell , similar to TurboAsm

Comment: If my memory serves me right (and it might not), it will declare `Var2` to hold the offset of where `Var1` is located inside the segment `Var1` is in. In the specific example of the question, the value of `Var2` would be 0, since `Var1` is the first declaration inside the segment.

Comment: Did you test it by declaring more variables before `Var1` and seeing if the value of `Var2` varied, as I said?

Comment: yes I did. it is just like you said

Comment: Then I'll move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable like this:

```
VARX    DW VARY
```

then you're basically saying:

```
VAR     DW (offset of VARY into the segment VARY is in)
```

In your specific example, `Var1` is the first variable in the data segment, so the declaration of `Var2`is equivalent to:

```
Var2   DW 0x0000
```

If, later on, you add more variables before `Var1`, in effect moving `Var1` further into the segment, the value of `Var2` will adjust correspondingly.

The typical usage of this is to get the start of array-like constructs by getting the address (offset in this context) of the start of the array.